# Higher torsions ($n$-torsions) in algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-groups, group-cohomology

How do we understand and define the concepts of higher torsions in algebraic topology?

Foe example, I know that the torsion group is related to the finite group sector of cohomology group or cobordism group, etc.

1. Is the common torsion group called 1-torsion?
2. How do we define 2-torsion? Is that part of cohomology group of $B^2G$?
3. How do we define 3-torsion? Is that part of cohomology group of $B^3G$?

Comment: What context would you like to compare it to? An element $x$ of a group/module/complex/etc... is $p$-torsion if $px=0$. It is higher $p$-torsion if $px\neq 0$ but $p^rx= 0$ for some $r>1$.

Comment: What are you talking about exactly?